# iOS app validation error: Missing plist key CFBundleShortVersionString

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, info.plist, spritebuilder

I built an iOS game with SpriteBuilder and cocos2d. When I attempt to submit it to the AppStore, I get the following error:

ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing plist key. The Info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleShortVersionString."

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is an easy fix. You just need to add the `CFBundleShortVersionString` key to your Info.plist file.

Click your `Info.plist` file in your project. Right click and select "Add Row". Then paste in the string "CFBundleShortVersionString". It will automatically change it to read: "Bundle versions string, short".

Then choose a value like `1.0` or whatever you want your version to be.

[image: Image of what your plist will look like after you add version]