# Expected token not found in attributes: CFBundleShortVersionString

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, plist, token

I have been trying to submit my app to the App Store, but haven't been able to get around this validation error. `"Expected token not found in attributes: CFBundleShortVersionString"`.

I thought it was simply just including `CFBundleShortVersionString` in my info plist and I would be okay.  However, that is not the case.

[image: error]

I have tried the solution here: [iOS app validation error: Missing plist key CFBundleShortVersionString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25717636/ios-app-validation-error-missing-plist-key-cfbundleshortversionstring)
But I am still getting this error.

I have cleaned my project, restarted my machine and Xcode, but now I am stuck trying to find a work around.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

[image: plist]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your short Bundle version string should be: `1.1`
Because your build version is `1.1.2`, i.e. the build 2 added.

Answer (score 0):

I found something to work around the problem.

I exported the .ipa file via Xcode and used Application Loader 3.0 to submit to the App Store. And it went through. The new build is now on iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

you only have to add Bundle Short Version String in info.plist of your project