# Receiving a very strange error stating "The Info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleShortVersionString key."

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, key, info.plist

When I built and compressed my app for submitting for Apple's review, I am displayed with the warning:

```
The Info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleShortVersionString key.
```

This is not contained in my Info.plist. Any help on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The `CFBundleShortVersionString` in your Info.plist identifies the version string for your app, such as 1.0 or 3.5.1. As your error implies, [it is required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25717712/4967340) in the Info.plist.

Simply open your project's Info.plist, choose Add Row, and enter `CFBundleShortVersionString`, which may change to "Bundle versions string, short". Set the type to String and the value to a version identifier for your app; use 1.0 if it's the first version. Now re-archive.

[image: Info.plist entry]

You should also be able to change the version string by going to the General tab of your **target** in Xcode.
[image: Target>General>Version]

Comment: I have added the row and the type of string simply states string. Not sure what specific category I should make it. In the open blank I have inputed 1.0 since it is my first version and I saved and compressed once more with the same error. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by "specific category"? Does setting Project > General > Version work?

Comment: A bit confused what you mean. I have identified it as "1" in the Bundle versions string, short with the word "string" unhighlighted.

Comment: Compare yours with the screenshots I just added, maybe try `1.0` instead. Any differences?

Comment: Scratch that I was able to fix it after constant trial and error but what is really pissing me off is this provisional profile error: ERROR ITMS-90174: "Missing Provisioning Profile - iOS Apps must contain a provisioning profile in a file named embedded.mobileprovision." Which is exactly what I did but where would I place it? Like I placed it inside my project folder but is there a specific location its supposed to be at?

Comment: Go to Build Settings for your target. Find "code signing" and next to provisioning profile, select the correct profile.

Comment: I have done exactly that with same error. For underneath in the Debug and Release areas, it is a mix with distribution and developer. Are they only supposed to be one of the following options and not both?

Comment: Should have specified, not Code Signing Identity, but Provisioning Profile. Make sure it is a valid provisioning profile. Also try going to Xcode preferences > Accounts > View Details > Refresh.

Comment: I have done that as well it keeps stating I need a provisioning profile called embedded.mobileprovision unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you, but this is clearly a [different question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30972472/4967340) (which you have already opened!).

Answer (score 0):

Swift3

Add `Bundle versions string, short` to `info.plist` like this Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turns out that Xcode wiped out the build number in an app extension I created. If you have any app extensions make sure that the version and build number are present.